# Java Date sort using compartor

Tags: java, sorting, date, collections, comparator

I am trying to sort a list of Dates and it's not working.

Here is the declaration and get function in AttemptEntity

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "end_time")
private Date endTime;

public Date getEndTime() {
    return endTime;
}
```

Here is the sorting code that isn't doing anything. GetAttempts() gets the list of all the attempts for called. They aren't in order, and I just want to be able to get whatever attempt has the latest endTime.

```
        List<AttemptEntity> attempts = called.getAttempts();
        Collections.sort(attempts, new Comparator<AttemptEntity>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(AttemptEntity a1, AttemptEntity a2) {
            if (a1.getEndTime() == null || a2.getEndTime() == null)
                return 0;
            return a1.getEndTime().compareTo(a2.getEndTime());
            }
        });
```

I believe that the code above should sort attempts, and then after it attempts should be sorted, so the latest end time would be attempts.get(attempts.size()-1).getEndTime()

I tried to use the following, and that didn't do any sorting at all either.  The input list and output list are exactly the same.

```
Comparator<AttemptEntity> comparator = Comparator.comparing(AttemptEntity::getEndTime).reversed();
attempts.sort(comparator);
```

Comment: If there is an Attempt without `endTime`, it would be considered by your `compare` method as equal to _every_ other instance. I'm not sure what a wildcard like that would do to a binary sort process.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looked fine to me in your code so gave a try with your code and I am able get the dates sorted, let me know if you are doing something different than below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class DateSorter {
    static List<AttemptEntity> attempts = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        prepareTestData();
        System.out.println(attempts);
        sortDates();
        System.out.println(attempts);
    }

    private static void sortDates() {
        Collections.sort(attempts, new Comparator<AttemptEntity>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(AttemptEntity a1, AttemptEntity a2) {
                if (a1.getEndTime() == null){
                    return 0;
                } else if(a2.getEndTime() == null){
                    return -1;
                }
                return a1.getEndTime().compareTo(a2.getEndTime());
            }
        });
    }

    private static void prepareTestData() {
        attempts = new ArrayList<>();
        attempts.add(new AttemptEntity(new Date(4444)));
        attempts.add(new AttemptEntity(new Date(1111)));
        attempts.add(new AttemptEntity(null));
        attempts.add(new AttemptEntity(new Date(3333)));
        attempts.add(new AttemptEntity(new Date(2222)));
    }
}
```

Test POJO:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class AttemptEntity {

    private Date endTime;

    AttemptEntity(Date date){
        endTime = date;
    }

    public Date getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return endTime == null ? null : endTime.toString();
    }

}
```

Final output:

```
[Thu Jan 01 05:30:04 IST 1970, Thu Jan 01 05:30:01 IST 1970, null, Thu Jan 01 05:30:03 IST 1970, Thu Jan 01 05:30:02 IST 1970]
[Thu Jan 01 05:30:01 IST 1970, Thu Jan 01 05:30:02 IST 1970, Thu Jan 01 05:30:03 IST 1970, Thu Jan 01 05:30:04 IST 1970, null]
```

---

**Update:** Looks like some NULL date could have caused some sorting issue, I have updated the `compare` method in above code.